# Rename subfolders in a directory without knowing part of the path

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, rename

The question is pretty simple, although I can't find the answer to my issue. I'm trying to create a 7z file from a folder, which its path is determined by the arguments of the definition. The problem is, that I need to rename a folder before creating that file. Thankfully, that "folder" has always the same name and the final name will always be the same. But the problem lies in the way to get to that path. That folder is always inside a folder which name can vary (it does not tend to do so, but at the long run is not feasible).
To put into perspective, this is the route:

```
carpetamareinicialresultant\\random-folder-that-can-vary\\folder-to-rename
```

The definition code at the moment goes like this:

```
def sevenzipoficial(tipus, cataleg, cançó, edició):
    if not os.path.exists(carpetamareinicial + '\\' + tipus + '\\' + cançó + '\\' + edició + ' - ' + cataleg):
        input('La carpeta inicial escollida no existeix. Pitja Enter per tornar al menú principal...')
        return -1
        menuprincipal = True
    carpetamareinicialresultant = os.path.join(carpetamareinicial, tipus, cançó, edició + ' - ' + cataleg + '\\', 'Discs' + '\\')  # Carpeta on està la música escollida
    carpetamarefinalresultant = os.path.join(carpetamarefinal, tipus, cançó, edició + ' - ' + cataleg + '\\') # Carpeta on es guardarà la música comprimida
    if not os.path.isfile(cataleg + '.7z'):
        print(subprocess.call(['7z', 'a', cataleg, '-p{racer21}', carpetamareinicialresultant]))
    if not os.path.exists(carpetamarefinalresultant):
        os.makedirs(carpetamarefinalresultant)
    if os.path.isfile(carpetamarefinalresultant + '\\' + cataleg + '.7z'):
        os.remove(carpetamarefinalresultant + '\\' + cataleg + '.7z')
    shutil.move(cataleg + '.7z', carpetamarefinalresultant)
```

PD: Also making that process get reverted after finishing is a bonus, but I guess I'd be the same process but changing some variables.

Comment: you might look at the `glob` module ( https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob )
That allows you to do things like:
`glob.glob("carpetamareinicial\\*\\Translated")`

Comment: The glob was the thing I needed, thanks! For those wondering, the result would look like this: `for carpetatraduit in glob.glob(carpetamareinicialresultant + '\\*\\'):
        if os.path.exists(carpetatraduit + 'Traduït'):
            os.rename(carpetatraduit + 'Traduït', carpetatraduit + 'Translated')`